# Nhibernate formula appending template word to sql keyword

Tags: nhibernate

I am using the following formula in my mapping file :

select top 1 SI.ID from Table SI with(nolock) where SI.GUID = GUID And SI.IsArchive = '0'

the genrated sql is :
select top 1 SI.ID from Table  SI **with(this_.nolock)** where SI.GUID = this_.GUID And SI.IsArchive = '0'

The nolock is a keyword. I don't want it to be qualified with this_.(template keyword).

how can I change this behaviour ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to refactor the formula logic into a user-defined function (assuming this is sql server here) and call that directly from the formula. You could even make the function part of your schema generation by using the database-object mapping.

For example:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetMyValue] ( @entityId INT ) 
    RETURNS INT
    AS BEGIN
      DECLARE @RtnValue AS INT 
      SELECT @RtnValue = top 1 SI.ID from Table SI with(nolock) where SI.id = @entityId AND SI.IsArchive = '0'
      RETURN @RtnValue
    END
```

And map as such

```
formula="dbo.GetMyValue(id)"
```

That should, in theory, prevent any sort of keyword replacement from happening.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to work around this with query substitutions in your nhibernate config; for example:

```
<property name="hibernate.query.substitutions">mynolock nolock</property>
```

And map as such:

```
select top 1 SI.ID from Table SI with(mynolock) where SI.GUID = GUID And SI.IsArchive = '0'
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if this would actually work or not (and it appears it doesn't); I do have another idea for you to try, I'll post it as a new answer...